# MySQL - Get left table elements although 'where' condition is not compatible

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables that matches a staff and his/her books. I want to get all staff in result although s/he has no books (count is 0). However, the code I wrote below returns only the staff that has at least one book compatible with `where` condition. How can I get all staff and the staff that has no book as having count 0?

```
SELECT staff.name AS sname, Count(book.book_id) AS bcount 
FROM db_staff AS staff 
LEFT JOIN db_book AS book ON book.staff_id = staff.staff_id 
WHERE (book.status_id = 1 OR book.status_id = 3) 
GROUP BY staff.staff_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the filter condition from `Where` to `And` clause, like so:

```
SELECT staff.name AS sname, Count(book.book_id) AS bcount 
FROM db_staff AS staff 
LEFT JOIN db_book AS book ON book.staff_id = staff.staff_id 
AND (book.status_id = 1 OR book.status_id = 3) 
GROUP BY staff.staff_id
```

Explanation: When there is a `where` clause, the `join` results are filtered, and rows which do not satisfy the condition are filtered out. When the same condition is made part of the `on` clause, it is treated as one of the `join` conditions. Hence, in a `left join`, the left side rows will be returned even if the right side does not have a row satisfying all conditions in the join.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75344/3

Comment: Yes, it worked. Is there any further info about that "AND" we used instead of "WHERE"?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use left outer join which select all the rows from left table regardless of its match to the right table in case it does not match it return null where in our case need zero
so here is the code .
isnull method convert null value to the value you mention.
`SELECT staff.name AS sname, Isnull(Count(book.staff_id),0) AS bcount FROM db_staff AS staff 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN db_book AS book ON book.staff_id = staff.staff_id 
    GROUP BY staff.staff_id`

Happie coding